# Como agregar dos botones dentro de un UITextField?

Tags: xcode, swift4

Buen dia.

Estoy intentando agregar dos botones dentro de un UITextField, pero solo me es posible agregar uno solo, de la siguiente manera.

```
let searchButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    searchButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_refresh"), for: .normal)
    searchButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -16, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    searchButton.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(10), y: CGFloat(5), width: CGFloat(25), height: CGFloat(25))
    searchButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.refresh), for: .touchUpInside)
    txtFacilitySearch.rightView = searchButton
    txtFacilitySearch.rightViewMode = .always
```

He intentado hacer otro botón para agregarlo de la misma manera pero siempre muestra uno solo.

En conclusion lo que quisiera lograr es lo siguiente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
De antemano gracias.

Answer (score 0):

No se como hacerlo en un UITexfield normal, creo que se puede en headers personalizados ya que te dejan agregar mas de un control y los va como alineando.

Otra solución es con Constraints, acomodas botones y el texfield, y haces que el textfield pase por debajo de los iconos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]